# Css sidebar menue outside curved

Tags: css

I have been trying to create a sidebar menue with outer curved affects. I have tried using before and after pseudos with border radius but I couldn't just figure it out.[this is what I am trying to make.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBtW6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

use the border-radius:16px; hope it will resolve your issue